# pointer point to const. Pointer changed but const no change

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
int main(void) {
    const int a = 2;
    int *p = (int *)&a;
    ++*p;
    cout << a << endl << *p << endl;
    cout << &a << endl << p << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

pointer point to `const int a` but when I change *pointer. `*p = 3` `a = 2`;
While p and a have the same address.
I don't know how it create to this result.
Can anyone explain for me. Thanks!

Comment: undefined behavior means anything can happen :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not allowed to modify const objects. Modifying a const object (through a non const pointer) has undefined behaviour. UB means that anything may happen. Having undefined behaviour is a programmers mistake.

While it's mostly pointless to reason about UB, in this case the observed behaviour is likely due to [constant folding](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding)

Comment: But it have the same address. This is my mistake, c++ mistake or something?

Comment: You must not modify const objects. But you did. It's your mistake. The address is irrelevant.

Comment: @DungNguyen the compiler replaced your `cout << a` with `cout << 2`, since `a` is a constant. It doesn't have to consider the possibility for `a` to change, even if you go out of your way for it, because doing so is explicitly forbidden. "Undefined behaviour" designates the discrepancy you observe : it makes no sense, nor is it required to, because the `const` contract has been broken.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is optimization. More precisely, constant propagation. Since `a` is declared to be constant and initialized to `2`, the compiler will simply hard-code `2` when calling `operator<<(ostream&, int)` since it will result in faster code than reading `a`'s contents again.

And it's legal: Since you've invoked undefined behavior, the compiler is free to do as it deems best.